# Efficient JOIN in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three large-ish tables, `A` (10 million rows), `A_C` (60 million rows) and `C` (6 rows). They are related via `bigint` fields and with primary foreign key relations. The tables have a n:m relation, this is why I added the `A_C` table. The schema is as follow:

`A.id = A_C.a_id` and
`C.id = A_C.c_id`

`A` is the primary table here. I want to display the first 100 entries from `A` and all corresponding rows from `C` via `A_C`. Currently the query takes very long. My first approach were two simple joins. Running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` I found out, that SQL does a sequential scan on `A`. I think this is because it applies the limit at last and simply disregards it. This performs very poorly. Is there any way to work around this `LIMIT` or another solution I am missing here? When I perform a `LIMIT` on a simple select query, it performs just fine in ~2ms.

Edit: `A.id` is primary key and has a btree index. `A_C` has a unique constraint on the entire row and also an index on `A_C.a_id` and `A_C.c_id`. I have not yet joined `C` as it is already really slow.

Fast queries:

- `SELECT A.id FROM A`
- `SELECT A.id FROM A LIMIT 10`

Slow query:

The following is fast in query planning but slow in execution since the data amount is very large:

- `SELECT A.id FROM A JOIN A_C ON A.id = A_C.a_id`

I tried to avoid that by setting a limit on how many rows from `A` are retrieved:

`SELECT a.id FROM (SELECT A.id AS id FROM metrics.metrics LIMIT 10) a JOIN A_C ON (a.id = A_C.a_id)`

The query plan via `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` looks as follows:

```
"Hash Join  (cost=5.75..1305897.53 rows=44790854 width=8) (actual time=251969.648..251969.648 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: (a_c.a_id = a.id)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on a_c  (cost=0.00..690017.54 rows=44790854 width=8) (actual time=0.472..126203.253 rows=44790000 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=4.50..4.50 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=1.889..1.889 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 12kB"
"        ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..3.50 rows=100 width=8) (actual time=0.527..1.550 rows=100 loops=1)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on a  (cost=0.00..261275.88 rows=7465088 width=8) (actual time=0.520..0.912 rows=100 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 16.350 ms"
"Execution time: 251969.693 ms"
```

Comment: What indexes do your tables have?  And what actual query did you run?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Without seeing the actual query, I don't think anyone, even Gordon Linoff, could give an answer here.  Note that if you were joining `A` to `A_C` and there were no `WHERE` clause, then a sequential scan of `A` might not be avoidable.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a subquery for the rows from `a`:

```
select . . .
from (select a.*
      from a
      order by a.id
      fetch first 100 rows only    -- or limit 100
     ) a join
     a_c ac
     on ac.a_id = a.id join
     c
     on ac.c_id = c.id;
```

Even though `c` is really small, I would encourage a primary key on `c(id)` if you don't already have one.

This assumes that "the first hundred rows" means by the ordering of the primary key.

Comment: Is `fetch first 10 rows only` different from `limit 10`?

Comment: @Freddy . . . Only in being the ANSI-compliant version.

Comment: thanks. I will try that out tomorrow, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Works perfectly!